# How to control the LEDs on Pepper QiSDK?

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, qi

On **NAOqi Framework 2.5** there was a module that allows you to control the LEDs of the robot called `ALLeds`.

Is there something similar, that allows me to control Pepper's LEDs?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't (as of January 2020) -  in Pepper QiSDK, the LED status is automatically function of Pepper's state (e.g. listening etc.).