# Pepper robot QiSDK-Changing color of the eye Leds

Tags: android, pepper

I'm working with pepper QiSDk. Is it possible to change the colors of the eye LEDs in pepper in android?

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to control the LEDs on Pepper QiSDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625754/how-to-control-the-leds-on-pepper-qisdk)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this feature is not available in the Qi SDK.